# Can you use an ability and scrap a card in the same turn?

Tags: star-realms

I'm pretty sure you can do this with my understanding of the rules, but my friend keeps arguing that you can't.

When you play a card like an "Explorer" for example. Can you in the same turn, use the 2 units to buy in the trade row and then scrap the card for 2 combat?

Explorer card for reference:

[image]

Comment: You can check out their official Android port for the game, not sure about iOS. Yes, I can do both on my turn with the official game.

Comment: @penguin359 Just upgraded my phone yesterday, thanks for the suggestion, I'll be getting it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Star Realms rules](http://www.starrealms.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/StarRealmsRules1.jpg), I think your interpretation is correct: **you may play a card for its trade value, then scrap it in the same turn.**

The relevant text (in the third row, top):

> When a Ship is played, its Primary Abjility triggers immediately.  If
>   a ship has an Ally and/or Scrap ability, you may choose to use **one or
>   both** of these abilities any time during your Main Phase (provided you
>   fulfill the obligations for doing so).

Your interpretation is supported too from the Main Phase description:

> At any time during your Main Phase, you may perform any of the following actions, in any order you wish:

And then finally, under **Using Abilities**:

> With the exception of a Ship's Primary Ability, players may use the various abilities of their in-play ships and Bases *at any time during their Main Phase*.  Each ability may be used just once each turn. (emphasis mine)

Since a ship has more than one ability (primary, scrap), each ability *is* only being used once per turn, too.

Comment: This is also how things work in the app.

Comment: While this doesn't detract from the answer, it's important to note that the mentioned rules *only* apply to Scrap effects from the target card.  You cannot, for example, use a Machine Cult "Scrap a card in my hand or discard" effect on a card that is played.  A card is drawn to the hand, put in play to use its abilities, and then put in the discard pile at the end of play in your turn, and cannot be in any two of those locations at one time.